# Wikidata / Sparql to return a range of numbers

Tags: sparql, wikidata

How would you write a SPARQL query to return wikidata items with Q-prefixed numbers between 1000 and 2000?

Comment: https://w.wiki/3ToF

Comment: @StanislavKralin nice solution, indeed limited by the max number. Minor comment. You should use `wd:` prefix for the items

Comment: Another option: https://w.wiki/3VAW